# Create generic / dynamically custom intents in Siri kit?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have created custom Intent for my app having custom UI for Siri and handled the Intent. I have also donated the intent to Siri Shortcut, added voice command to use it from Siri.

Is there a way to use Siri Shortcuts as a generic?
For example, for a set of voice commands a particular Siri shortcut gets fired, while for another set of voice commands another shortcut?

Or, further, in case we wanted to create shortcuts (using either NSUserActivity or Intents) when new scenarios appear in my app for which I want to add new shortcuts, is there a way to add them dynamically without having to submit a new app version?

Answer (score 2):

No, as of now you can not pass dynamic entities in your custom SiriKit Intents. You can only use Siri Shortcuts which assume that all the required information has been provided while donating the shortcut.

In layman's terms, Shortcuts are way to fire a workflow using a specific command. So while you can "Hey Siri, What is my Profile Rep Point" but you can not say "Hey Siri, What is the Rep Point Count for {userName} Profile".

Regarding getting dynamic Intent Creations for your app is only possible If your app does fall into SiriKit Supported Domains since the "machine learning" capabilities of Siri have been for now provided to those domains only.

Let's hope this WWDC Apple does finally open up SiriKit for many other domains as well.

Cheers!

**EDIT: 22/01/2019:**
As of iOS 13, Apple has enabled **conversational** Siri Shortcuts soa as to stimulate support conversational interaction in Siri. Using this you can create Dynamic Custom Intents for your app, but the oly caveat is that this works for devices with iOS 13+. Devices with iOS 12 or below will not support Conversational Intents and may cause errors.